# I'm facing Xpath Query Challenge for Google Sheet Import XML funtion

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I want to import data (Like Website URL of this person, Social Media Links like Facebook and Twitter into Google Sheet from the following Realtor's profile link:

https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/568117e3bb954c0100693e2c

But when I apply the 'ImportXML" function by copying 'Full Xpath Query' from the inspect section like this and press enter Key:

> =IMPORTXML("https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/5682d84c7e54f70100200a6b","/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]//@href")

The result shows an error and this is written in the cell #N/A and a message shows:

> 'imported content is empty'

I tried many times to apply IMPORTXML funtion in the Google sheet and I was expecting that the data such as link website URL and social links will be fectched automatically but all in vain and it just shows #N/A and a short message: "imported content is empty"

Comment: About `Yes, that's correct`, now, I understood your current issue. In your question, you are showing one URL. But, you have 7741 URLs. Unfortunately, my answer is for your showing URL. I cannot know your other 7740 URLs and your expected 7740 results. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. When I could correctly understand all of them, I would like to try to think of a solution. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because my answer is for your provided one URL. I apologize for my poor skill again. I would like to study more.

Comment: Thank You so much Tanaike for being with me at least You helped me for my one URL. I'm again very thankful to You for such a humble and kind support.
Stay Blessed!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that in the case of your question, it is required to know more information about your expected input and output situations. Because, in the current stage, I cannot know your current issue. In order to help to think of your current issue, can you update your question by including more information? By this, I would like to think of a solution, again. About this, can you cooperate to resolve your issue? By the way, I'm worried whether the values can be correctly retrieved from 7741 URLs. So, as the first step, how about testing a small number of URLs?